# How to use a variable in an xpath query?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have an xpath that needs some replacement of text to work:

```
response.xpath("//h2[@class='brownBackground']/a[@href='/friend/user/4074594-kiki']/text()")
```

However, this `href='/friend/user/4074594-kiki'` value needs to be returned based on the URL:

```
x='/friend/user/'+''.join(re.findall(r'https://www.goodreads.com/user/show/(.*)','https://www.goodreads.com/user/show/4074594-kiki'))
```

when I use:

```
response.xpath("//h2[@class='brownBackground']/a[@href=x]/text()")
```

it stops working. I suspect it is because the quotation marks `""` make the path string literals, thus `x` does not return the `x` value anymore, but the `"x"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's not going to magically start replacing characters in strings with the content of variables that happen to be in scope - that would be *insanely* frustrating! If you want to put `x` into the string, **be explicit**:

```
response.xpath(
    "//h2[@class='brownBackground']/a[@href={!r}]/text()".format(x)
)
```

See the documentation on [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).